# Delete .aux file in order to successfully compile

Tags: compiling

From time to time I need to prepare presentations, and I use the `beamer` class plus the `minted` package.

I would like to know why sometimes I need to delete the `aux` file generated by `pdflatex` to successfully compile. Is there any additional step aside from invoking `pdflatex`?

Comment: perhaps compiling it with `latexmk -pdf` would help (you can even set up a `latexmkrc` file with instructions about what kind of files should be cleaned up after the compilation)

Comment: Usually when this happens to me it's after a failed compile so maybe there's some bad data in the .aux file that latex is still trying to use which is now invalid (usually happens when you quit compiling or end the pdflatex command after it finds an error without letting it complete)

Comment: @henrique that is a good advice. I haven't considered using latexmk because my projects are rather simple, but maybe it is time to switch. Thank you

Comment: @JesusRamos That is my scenario, after a failed compile.

Comment: @amorenoc Do you select any options to take or do you hit CTRL-C and exit the pdflatex compiler by selecting an option when it encounters the error?

Comment: I just hit Ctrl-C, when it finds some error. Normally shows a question mark and mention about runaway argument.

Comment: @JesusRamos your question has answered my question. As simple as press `X` to quit, rather than just sent a `SIGINT` to the process. I would accept that as an asnwer :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens because of abnormal termination of pdflatex. To avoid this instead of killing pdflatex, use the X option at the error prompt to quit instead.

Took me a while to figure this out (mostly because upon error emacs compilation buffer is read only, so I always had to force it to close)

Comment: How do you do it then in emacs?

Comment: I just use M-x term or M-x shell to do it so that I still get an interactive shell and a Makefile. Or you can use AuCtEx to do it as well.

Comment: There are other reasons for aux error e.g. when a package is removed and the package writer does not consider that case.