# Unable to compile TeXmaker 4.0.2 with MiKTeX 2.9

Tags: errors, compiling, texmaker

I just downloaded first MiKTex 2.9 and then TeXmaker 4.0.2. However, I am having a hard time getting it to compile. I always get the info box saying `Can't detect the file name` followed by the info box saying `Could not start the command`.

In the `Configure Texmaker` -> `Commands` options box I have set the path in the bottom to:

> "C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin"

I have also tried putting this file path in the specific command paths above (together with the filenames). But neither helps. I have been looking around at this and other Tex pages, and other people have asked the same question. I have tried to do, what they were advised to do, but is has not help.

I hope that somebody can help me.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Have you done [Verify a latex installation: Commandline/Terminal](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101890/15717) to see output.pdf

Comment: for pdflatex in TeXmaker see if you have `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex` in pdflatex command box. You might need to restart the windows to take the miktex bin path into effect

Comment: Did you save the file that you edited? I recently forgot that and had a similar error.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! Yeah, I have written the "pdflatex -syn...." in the pdflatex command line.

Comment: When I am refering to where I wrote the path for the bin-folder, I am refering to what I wrote in the "Add to PATH" commmand line. Is this correct?

Comment: The LaTeX script that I am trying to run is the following one:

>\begin{document}
>Hello World!
>\end{document}

Comment: Okay, now I got it to compile - unlike TeXworks, Texmaker does not force you to save when you are compiling, but instead comes up with the above mentioned message...

Comment: @Marcus `pdflatex` or `latex` engine needs `filename.tex` file which is created by TeXmaker only when you save it with filename. there is no need to touch the "Add to PATH" commmand line in TeXmaker. Once MiKTeX is installed and Computer is restarted you will get miktex bin path automatically  added to system PATH. So the default configuration works. Incase you need add `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex` to `pdflatex` and `latex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex` for `latex` in TeXmaker configure command box

Comment: @Marcus converted the comments along with common errors in TeXmaker to an answer to benefit future users.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Common newbie mistakes/errors Using TeXmaker

1. From Version 4.1 onwards, `A document must be saved with an extension (and without spaces or accents in the name) before being used by a command` pops out when the file is compiled (Press QuickBuild) before saving it as `file-name.tex`.

   - Save the file as `file-name.tex` and then compile using `QuickBuild` or `PDFLATEX`.

2.`cannot detect file-name` and `Could not start the command` errors:

- In TeXmaker one needs to **save** `.tex` code  as `file-name.tex` before compiling otherwise above errors pop out. In TeXworks, it's better handled by suggesting the `untitled-1.tex` file name before compiling.

  3. Error: Log file not found! :[Texmaker (Windows version) - first use - Error: Log file not found!](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63999/15717).

     - when compiling a `.tex` document in TeXmaker without installing LaTeX distribution [MiKTeX](http://docs.miktex.org/2.9/manual/installing.html)/[TeXLive](http://www.tug.org/texlive/)/[MacTeX](http://www.tug.org/mactex/index.html) etc. Since TeXmaker is just like any LaTeX editor needs LaTeX distribution to compile `.tex` and output `.pdf`
     - "Note : a LaTeX distribution must be installed on the system to use TeXmaker" at [TeXmaker Download page](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html) .
     - [Verify a latex installation: Commandline/Terminal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101890/15717) after installation and In MiKTeX, after installation,Computer needs a restart to get miktex bin path added to system PATH automatically.
  4. "File not found" error: [TexMaker - "File not found" when viewing as pdf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45900/15717). when the `file-name.pdf` is not available/generated from `file-name.tex` during compilation due to following **reasons**:solutions
- **Wrong output file path** :uncheck "build" subdirectory in Configure window
- **Lack of read/write output folder permissions** : copy `file-name.tex` to another folder and compile
- **renamed `file-name.pdf`** : `file-name.tex` and `file-name.pdf` names should be same
- **Missing `file-name.pdf`** : Incase of `latex` compilation only `-file-name.dvi` is only available, one may need `dvips` and `ps2pdf` to get `compiled-file.pdf`
- **`file-name.pdf` locked by another pdf-viewer** : Close the external pdf-viewer
- **Unable to generate `file-name.pdf`**: Delete improper `.aux` files and why to [Delete .aux file in order to successfully compile](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49462/15717)
- Common newbie errors [Unable to generate pdf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111967/15717) encountered in TeXniccenter are are applicable to TeXmaker as well.

  5. Finally configure TeXmaker whenever necessary as defaults work fine.

     - Typical command line arguments to place in the [configure TeXmaker window](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/doc.html#SECTION0) :adding flag `-synctex=1` to enable synctex and `-shell-escape` to run external programs(when neccessary)
     - `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`
     - `latex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`
     - `xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`

Related Links:

- [Impossible to save LaTeX file in Texmaker on Windows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/106100/15717) from TeXmaker version 4.0 and 4.0.1 (compiled with Qt5).
- [TeXmaker documentation](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/doc.html) and [Installation Screenshot tutorials (FR)](http://www.xm1math.net/doculatex/index.html#install)
- [PdfLaTeX in Texmaker doesn’t work: “Could not start the command”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107110/15717)
- [Biblatex + Biber + Texmaker + MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44040/15717)
- [Configure forward search with Texmaker + SumatraPDF](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37327/15717)

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem and tried pretty much everything mentioned in the above answer with no luck. What worked for me though is uninstalling MiKTex and reinstalling a 64-bit version as administrator (for all users). I read this solution somewhere and it worked. I am sorry I don't know the reason why it worked.

Comment: This has quite probably nothing to do with 32-bit vs. 64-bit version, but you did obviously a clean reinstallation. BTW perhaps also important for you: [How can one install biber on miktex 64-bit?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154708). And what I notice just now: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: This seems more appropriate as a comment, as it does not necessarily answer the question but suggests one way that the OP might troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: @Adam However, that's what multiple answers are for: That people see the multiple options they have. And voting is for giving feedback as which asnwer is more correct, or which solution is preferable.

Comment: a clean install is an easy way to reset paths, perhaps reinstalling TeXMaker might have done the job in itself.

Answer (score 0):

It happens to me too, and I solved it, the reason is I have already opened MiKTeX, and try to use build function in TeXmaker, you just need to close MiKTeX, and try quick build again.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the problem of 'log file not found'. When I removed spaces in the file name of my tex document it compiled succesfully! I am baffled as previous documents compiled even with spaces in the file name.

Comment: That should be better a comment ...

Comment: Does anyone have an answer to this?