# MikTeX and TeXmaker are unable to compile

Tags: miktex, texmaker

Please, I need help with some issues that happens with my TeX editors. I've installed MikTeX and TeXmaker on my computer and I got some troubles:

The first of them is, when I try to compile my `.tex` file on MikTeX, there are no errors, the program only generates `.aux` and `.log` files, no `.pdf` files are generated during the compilation.

The second is, I've saved a file in my Hard Drive and try to compile it, but TeXmaker returns an error message saying

`> File not found.`

I don't know what should I do. Please I need help because I need to compile an article to bring to my professor.

This is the content of .txt file. I really don't understando that.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2013.5.22)  22 MAY 2013 13:14
entering extended mode
**C:/Users/Luis*Jr/Documents/Tex.tex
("C:/Users/Luis Jr/Documents/Tex.tex"
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, 
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2012-05-30, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian,
 lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, n
german-x-2012-05-30, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, roman
ian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerm
an, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usengl
ishmax, welsh, loaded.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Users\Luis Jr\Documents\Tex.aux")
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
 ("C:\Users\Luis Jr\Documents\Tex.aux") ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 201 strings out of 493921
 2252 string characters out of 3144870
 49031 words of memory out of 3000000
 3582 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 841 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 23i,1n,17p,162b,36s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s

No pages of output.
PDF statistics:
 0 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

When I compile a `.tex`, in case, trying to compile `Tex.tex` the compiler only generates a `.aux` and a `.txt` like the image above.

[Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jsch.png)

Comment: And what does the log-file say? Regarding the file not found error: Make sure to add the extension .tex when saving the file.

Comment: Could you please add a minimal working example of your document? For me it looks like your TeXmaker is not properly connected to your MikTeX installation

Comment: Are you using pdflatex to compile or any other profile like dvi or ps?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX, You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Please  look at some of issues [Unable to compile TeXmaker 4.0.2 with MiKTeX 2.9](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/113680/15717)

Comment: I've made a mistake, there's no .log files. Only a text and a .aux files.

Comment: I'm using pdf latex to compile.

Comment: please ping @Sensei like this "I'm using pdf latex to compile." otherwise it will not be notified to right username. is your problem resolved now ?.

Comment: The `.txt` file you are showing *is* the log-file. Adapt your settings so that windows doesn't hide the extension `.log`. The log-file shows that `pdflatex` is working fine. But your document seems to have no content and so doesn't generate a page. Write something after `\begin{document}` in `tex.tex`.