# Texmaker gives an error: could not start the command

Tags: errors, texmaker

The Texmaker version is 4.0.2.

I have installed the TeXworks a couple of months ago and it works fine. Now I want to try TeXmaker, and it gives

> `error: could not start the command`

[image]

I just checked that `C:/Program Files/Asymptote/asy.exe` and `C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.07/bin/gswin32c.exe` do not exist

Comment: Please have a look at this answer [Unable to compile TeXmaker 4.0.2 with MiKTeX 2.9](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/113680/15717) and based on your position/error apply the related trick assuming [MiKTeX](http://miktex.org/download) is installed properly and test the installation by typing at commandline window `pdflatex sample2e` to get `sample2e.pdf`. BTW Latest TeXmaker is now [4.0.3](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html#windows)

Comment: My guess: You might need to save the file as `filename.tex` before running `QuickBuild`. Make sure [Ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html) is installed incase of `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` route compilation/PSTricks otherwise use `pdflatex` compilation.

Comment: @texenthusiast I m using windows. and it says the pdflatex is not recognized as an internal or external command. And the file is saved before I try to compile it.

Comment: may be MiKTeX PATH is not set properly test the installation with `pdflatex sample2e` at commandline window to ensure if it's correct

Comment: In Worst case `Options`-->`Settings file`-->`Reset settings` and Remember to save the settings file somewhere for backup incase required. Restart TeXmaker so that TeXmaker automatically configures the `latex` `dvips` executables

Comment: @texenthusiast in the command line, I entered the folder that contains pdflatex, and run pdflate sample2e, it gives "This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.
entering extended mode
! I can't write on file `sample2e.log'." I haven't tried the reset yet.

Comment: change directory(cd) to `Desktop` and run from that commandline window or any where folder where you have write permission , don't go to MiKTeX bin folder

Comment: @texenthusiast   in cmd, how to deal with the spaces in the command, like this C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\pdflatex example2e

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9929/discussion-between-texenthusiast-and-tiina)

Comment: i recommand TexStudio +MicTex. Texworks, Texmaker Texmakerx TexStudio this 4 editors i think TexStudio is the best . it's personal view, it's up to you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Please have a look at this answer [Unable to compile TeXmaker 4.0.2 with MiKTeX 2.9](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/113680/15717) and based on your position/error apply the related trick assuming [MiKTeX](http://miktex.org/download) is installed properly and test the installation by following steps

- when you run `cmd` from `Start Menu` search it would open at `C:\Users\username>`
- type `cd Desktop` to get `C:\Users\username\Desktop>`
- now type `pdflatex sample2e` to get `sample2e.pdf` then it is confirmed that installation is working properly and Path is set ok.
- also Type at `C:\Users\username\Desktop>` Path to see if there is MiKTeX bin like `C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\bin` depending where it was installed on 32 bit or 64 bit OS and MiKTeX Distro

Latest TeXmaker is [4.0.3](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html#windows)
released on July 29th 2013.

In Worst case `Options`-->`Settings file`-->`Reset settings` and Remember to save the settings file somewhere for backup incase required. Restart TeXmaker so that TeXmaker automatically configures the latex dvips executables

Note : You might need to save the file as `filename.tex` before running `QuickBuild`. Make sure [Ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html) is installed incase of `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` route compilation/PSTricks otherwise use `pdflatex` compilation.

Answer (score 7):

For those of you who have MiKTeX install but still can't seem to solve this even with the other answers here, I found a solution (for Windows).

If you have have both **MiKTeX** and **Texmaker** installed on Windows, but get the `could not start the command` error, try this:

1. Locate the `pdflatex.exe` file. This is a file which should have been installed along with MiKTeX. Go to the folder in with MiKTeX was installed. Use the search feature to find `pdflatex.exe`. Right click on it and copy the file path, so what you copied should be something like this: `C:\path\to\pdflatex.exe`. If you don't copy the end `pdflatex.exe` (because Windows only shows the file path excluding the name in the About box) don't worry, you can append `\pdflatex.exe` to it later!
2. Go to Texmaker and click Options > Configure Texmaker
3. In the page that comes up the second label you'll see is called "PdfLaTeX." It the box next to it you need to paste the path in. Select the word `pdflatex` which is in that box and paste the file path in. Don't forget to put it in quotes! Now, in that box, you should see something like this: `"C:\path\to\pdflatex.exe" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`
4. Click okay and you're good to go! Try building something. You shouldn't see an error now.

Hopefully this helps someone and saves them from a lot of searching!

Answer (score 5):

it is very simple, in that box, you should see something like this: "C:\path\to\pdflatex.exe" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex

- enter to local c.
- enter to program or prgrame file.
- search about MiKTeX 2.9
- search about miktex
- search about bin
- search about x64
- search about pdflatex.exe
- copy the link as: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe
- open text maker and follow Options > Configure Texmaker
- past it PdfLatex field as: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
- and it will be run successful INCHALLAH.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: Works for me. 
 In my understanding, Textmaker needs to run "pdflatex.exe" to compile. In this case, because it cannot find pdflatex.exe provided by MiKTeX, we manually let Textmaker know where pdflatex.exe is by setting as the above.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install TeX Live. Then it can start the command.
 `http://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html`

Comment: This answer needs more upvotes. I had the same problem. When you install TexMaker it actually doesn't install all the packages. You also need Tex Live.

Answer (score 0):

I simply changed the `pdflatex` to `lualatex.exe` under the build section..
worked for me :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Compiling with `lualatex` instead of `pdflatex` is not really the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using linux, to solve the problem, get installed `biber` and `biblatex` on your system by these command lines:

```
sudo apt-get install biber
sudo apt-get install biblatex
```

This is in case where you are making the bibliography with `biblatex`.