# MikTeX: Trying to use Asymptote with Texmaker

Tags: miktex, texmaker, asymptote

I installed Asymptote and I'm trying to set it up with Texmaker so that I can compile Asymptote code within the tex document.

The problem is that I'm getting this error:

```
Error : could not start the command : "C:/Program Files/Asymptote/asy.exe" "C:/Users/abcde/Desktop/Documents/Test/Document-1".asy
```

Comment: please have a look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126510/texmaker-gives-an-error-could-not-start-the-command

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you try the suggestions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126510/texmaker-gives-an-error-could-not-start-the-command)?

Comment: @teapot I had already been using Texmaker and it was working fine, the problem is trying to setup Asymptote with it. Do you think that thread is still relevant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since August 2017, Asymptote has been integrated into MikTeX and therefore the previous answers are no longer valid.

For asymptote to work correctly under Texmaker, the asymptote command must be correctly initialized in Texmaker.
By default, it displays:
`"C:/Program Files/Asymptote/asy.exe" %.asy`

This is **not** the right path to the asymptote executable.

#### 1. Found the MikTeX installation folder by clicking on the MikTeX console `Settings` `Directories`tab

Asymptote is installed in the folder highlighted in yellow here, it is about `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64`

[image: screenshot]

But, by default, MikTeX is installed in the folder

```
C:\Users\cs\AppData\Local\Programs\MikTeX2.9
```

Then just copy this path and add `\asy.exe" %.asy`

In my case, this is: `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\asy.exe %.asy`

By default, you will get `C:\Users\cs\AppData\Local\Programs\MikTeX2.9\miktex\bin\x64\asy.exe %.asy`

#### 2. Just configure Texmaker by clicking on `configure`

[image: configure texmaker]

and then copy this path without forgetting the `%.asy` and it's over.

`"C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\asy.exe" %.asy`

#### 3. New Year Update 2020.

I just wrote to Pascal Brachet, Texmaker developer, to change the default asymptote path on Texmaker.
[Version 5.0.4 of Texmaker](https://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/log.html) has just been released. The default paths to the asymptote executable `asy.exe` has been updated.

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for your answer. But, for some reason, I can't find the `asy.log` file in `C:\Users\your-name-on-windows\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log`.

Comment: Open the `PowerShell` console from any folder. Once opened type the command `asy` it will create the file `asy.log`

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't see the rest of the answer. Also, not sure why but I can't find miktex in my program files. Should I consider reinstalling?

Comment: No, it's no use, open the MikTeX management console, you'll find the installation folder there. I just updated my answer.

Comment: Alright, sorry for the confusion. It works now, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Good if you succeeded. Your problem made me look for a long time and I thank you for it *(I like to look for it)*. I have just found a simpler way to do it and I have simplified my solution. Do you think my last solution is easier to understand now?

Comment: Yeah, your new solution is a bit easier to understand now. My main confusion was with the different directory for the MikTeX installation folder. Maybe it has to do with the fact that I installed it maybe a year ago.

Comment: Good, have a good evening:-)