# Problem with compilng a .tex file in Texmaker

Tags: pdftex, errors, texmaker

My hard drive burned out a few days ago - and once I bought a new one and reinstalled Texmaker, it refuses to compile any .tex files I make. Even something as basic as:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Hello World!
    
\end{document}
```

Always gives the same message:

> Error : could not start the command : pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "FileName".tex.

There is nothing else in the log.

What could cause this?

Comment: Have you installed not only the editor TeXmaker, but also a TeX distribution (either MiKTeX or TeX Live)? What happens, if you try `pdflatex --version` in a terminal window? See also, e.g. [New installation – TeX editor says: "Error: Could not start the command"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84357/277964) or “[Texmaker gives an error: could not start the command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/126510/277964)” and several more [related questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Btexmaker%5D+%5Berrors%5D+command).

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem - I installed TeXmaker so long ago, that I forgot that MiKTeX is a separate entity. Very silly of me. Thanks for the help!