# TeXMaker on Windows: "Could not start the command"

Tags: texlive, texmaker, windows

I can not start pdfLaTeX from TeXMaker in Windows 7. I try `Quick Building` with `Pdflatex+Viewer` but I'm getting the error: "Could not start the command". I have installed TexLive 2013.

I added the bin filepath to my enviromental PATH variable and I am able to run pdfLaTeX and all other commands from cmd without problems. I also tried specifying the full path in texmaker as: `C:\texlive\2013\bin\win32\pdflatex.exe` but the same error pops up. Am I missing something?

Comment: Take a look at this thread: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/113433/27635

Comment: BTW: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Hello karlkoeller, thanks for the welcome! I've already browsed through similar questions but all suggest the same things: Installing a TeX distribution (already done), taking care of the paths for the binaries (already done) and checking from the cmd if I can compile my .tex file. I've done all these, but for some reason my TeXMaker doesn't start the command from the GUI.

Comment: What does `pdflatex --version` at the Command Prompt give?

Comment: @JosephWright

` pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 <TeX Live 2013/W32TeX>
kpathsea version 6.1.1 
...some copyright and warranty info...
Compiled with libpng 1.5.16; using lipbng 1.5.16
Compiled with zlib 1.2.7; using zlib 1.2.7
Compiled with xpdf version 3.03 `