# Error: "A document must be saved with an extension (and without spaces or accents in the name) before being used by a command"

Tags: errors, texmaker

I am new to LaTeX and was trying out this today:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\title{Latex}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

But as I run it, it says Error: `A document must be saved with an extension (and without spaces or accents in the name) before being used by a command`.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! That doesn't seem a LaTeX error message. Can you tell us what operating system, TeX distribution and editor you're using?

Comment: And please consider revising the question title to reflect the content instead of your current situation.

Answer (score 3):

Try to save your document before compiling,if you haven't done it yet.

Answer (score 1):

From [Version 4.1](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/log.html) onwards, Texmaker gives more meaningfull error compared to the earlier `Could not start the command` error, but unfortunately it does not prompt for SAVE dialog box with `untitled-1.tex` like TeXworks.

> A document must be saved with an extension (and without spaces or accents in the name) before being used by a command.

So as [alessandro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/40868/alessandro) suggested save it first with a good `file-name.tex` and compile later.

- Save the file as `file-name.tex` and then compile using `QuickBuild` or `PDFLATEX`.

Please refer also [Common newbie mistakes/errors Using Texmaker](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/113680/15717)