# Using Latex on win10

Tags: errors, miktex, texmaker

I just installed basic-miktex-22.3-x64 on C:\Miktex and then installed Texmaker_5.1.3_Win_x64, when I tried to run this: I get on **Could not start the command.
"C:/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64/latex.exe" -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex**

How can fix that please?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  Hello World!
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to compile TeXmaker 4.0.2 with MiKTeX 2.9](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113433/unable-to-compile-texmaker-4-0-2-with-miktex-2-9)

Comment: This is not a solution to my problem

Comment: can you compile on a command line?

Comment: You say you installed in `C:\Miktex` but TeXmaker is looking for `C:\Miktex 2.9`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, How can check that please?

Comment: I delete the previous one and create C:\Miktex 2.9 and I get the same error!!! :(

Comment: Go in the Windows explorer to the folder of your test tex document. Type cmd into the address bar and hit enter. That should open a terminal window where you then can type pdflatex your-file to start a compilation

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, this is the out put \Desktop\lat>pdflatex new.tex
'pdflatex' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: any help please? I want to use latex :((

Comment: With the given information, it is difficult to diagnose your problem. Try uninstalling MiKTeX and reinstalling it with the default options.