# Texmaker unable to compile

Tags: texmaker

I'm trying to compile and run a textmaker document however I keep getting this error even though I have already installed miktex. Any solutions?

[image]

Comment: Note that is will also be useful to know exactly which operating system you're using. MikTeX is mostly used on windows, but is also available on other systems where installation can be tricky and this thus often not recommended on those systems.

Answer (score 0):

The most possible cause of this problem is that MikTeX isn't add to PATH. To solve this problem, you can open the MikTeX Console. There should be a warning, prompting you to add MikTeX to PATH.

As an alternative, you can go to Control Panel, and search for "Edit the system environment variables".

[image: Screenshot1]

Click on "Environment Variables...".

In the "User variables for [username]" section, double click "Path". Then click "New", and enter the path to your MikTeX installation folder. The default path is `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\`. (WARNING: it might be different.)

If it still doesn't work, you can consider switching to [TeXstudio](https://www.texstudio.org/), which in my opinion is better than TeXmaker.

You can also see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113433/unable-to-compile-texmaker-4-0-2-with-miktex-2-9), for more possibilities.